# How to setup 410 permanently deleted on nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code

How do I setup 410 permanently deleted on nginx for a specific URL for e.g.

`https://www.example.com/product/somepage.html`

Or better yet how can I do it for a specific prefix for e.g.

`https://www.example.com/product/`

Here I want to 410 all URLs that are `/product/` for e.g. `/product/page1.html`, `/product/page2.html` etc.

Here's my current conf setup.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index portal.php index.php  index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.example.com;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
          expires 1M;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
          add_header Pragma public;
        }

        location ~ ^/\.user\.ini {
                deny all;
        }
        
        #some more config here
}
```

Comment: Post it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`return` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) to generate the required status response.

A [`location` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) with the `^~` operator is probably best as it cannot be overridden by other regular expression locations.

For example:

```
location ^~ /product/ { 
    return 410; 
}
```